# How to split string with text and numbers but the numbers are separated by comma?

Tags: python, regex

I'm quite newbie in doing Regex and I wonder what syntax of regex that can help me for this one

Let say I have a string s

```
"Balance Quantity 430,000.00 Total Buy 380,000.00"
```

I want to separate the string to get

```
["Balance Quantity","430,000.00","Total Buy","380.000,00"]
```

So, basically split the string and the number.

Now I already search and try to use this syntax

```
re.split(r'(\d+)', s)
```

But actually produce like below
`['Balance Quantity ', '430', ',', '000', '.', '00', ' Total Buy ', '380', ',', '000', '.', '00', '']`

Can anyone help me to solve this ?

Comment: Is there a need to handle something like `Batch3 333,333.00` or `Balance, negative 444,444.0`?

Comment: More like also to handle something like Balance -234,450.00
But both cases you mention no need

Answer (score 2):

I use `re.split(r' *([\d,.]+) *', s)` to split string and `list(filter(None, result))` to remove none string.

```
import re

a = "Balance Quantity 430,000.00 Total Buy 380,000.00"

b = list(filter(None, re.split(r' *([\d,.]+) *', a)))
['Balance Quantity', '430,000.00', 'Total Buy', '380,000.00']
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of just picking out streams of digits `(\d+)`, you can pick out streams of all the characters that occur in your numbers: `([\d,.]+)`.

So you could use something like this:

```
>>> re.split(r'([\d,.]+)', s)
['Balance Quantity ', '430,000.00', ' Total Buy ', '380,000.00', '']
```

Answer (score 0):

`split` has a property that if the argument contains capturing groups, they are included in the result. So, one possible solution would be to create a regex for numbers only, make it capturing and `split` by it, for example:

```
numbers_re = r'''(?x)

    (           # make it capturing

        \d+     # digits
        (?:     # a group of comma+digits 0 or more times
            ,
            \d+
        )*
        (?:    # a group of dot+digits, 0 or 1 time
            \.
            \d+
        )?

    )
'''


r = re.split(numbers_re, s)
```

`(?x)` in the regex means "verbose mode", with whitespace and comments - recommended for readability.